# Could anyone give me a simple example to prove inheritance for implementation is evil?

Tags: oop, composition

The illustration below is the example in my lecture slide, I'm know about C++

And For me with some ruby knowledge, Vector is like `Array` with random access and Stack is the one without, so I seem inheritance is reasonable  for me. so could anyone gives me a more simple example? or explanation what's wrong with my understanding?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the key to the reason why inheritance is not a good idea in this case:

```
Vector is like Array with random access and Stack is the one without
```

Broadly speaking, inheritance is there for you to provide *additional* behaviour; there is no reasonable* way to *remove* behaviour.

So if `Stack` extends `Vector` it will inherit the random access behaviour (and contract) provided by the `Vector` class, which is something you don't want.

Think about inheritance in terms of **is-a****. Does it make sense to say a `Stack` **is-a** `Vector`? If not, then it shouldn't extend `Vector`.

The fact that you can implement a `Stack` using a `Vector` is not relevant to the `Stack` interface. As @Patashu has pointed out, you want to be able to change implementation if you need to without changing the contract. Maybe, for example, you want to use a linked list implementation rather than a `Vector`. If you extend `Vector` this is not possible; if you use composition it's pretty trivial.

*Of course you can override methods to remove the behaviour you don't want, but that would break the `Vector` contract and will make things very confusing for your users. That's why it's usually not reasonable to do this.

****is-a** has its own pitfalls, like anything else in software architecture: see the [Circle-Ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) for a good example of why you need to be extra-careful when deciding which class inherits from what.

Comment: I've switch the child and parent, is it okay now? I think `vector` should have all the methods in `stack`

Comment: No, that still fails the `is-a` test. A `Stack` is a FIFO (first-in-first-out) structure. A `Vector` is a random-access structure. They are fundamentally different and neither should inherit from the other.

Comment: I mean a LIFO (last-in-first-out), of course. A queue is a FIFO.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think about it in terms of a codebase that is being written for other people, and so has to support other peoples' usage, or if YOUR code is using said other codebase. When it's just your code, you can make changes easily because you're in control of everything, but if other people have to be supported you have to be aware of what changes can make other people's code break.

1) If you inherit from a class, you have to support the same contract as the class. By contract I mean the public facing methods form a set of promises that the class can carry out. This can be bad if a) its contract is unwieldy for your class b) the class you inherit from's contract changes from under you.

2) By composing instead of inheriting, you can change what you use for your class's implementation without making any breaking public changes, and thus a lot quicker and cheaper, like if you decided 'I don't want to use Vector for my stack implementation, I want to use DifferentVector instead' it would break code assuming your stack is a subclass of Vector.

3) Plus, even if you are not using inheritance for your stack-that-is-backed-by-vector, you can still have both Stack and Vector implement the ICollection interface (for example) allowing them to be used interchangeably and polymorphic, which is the main advantage of doing inheritance in the first place.